# Give function scope access to the self where it is called?

Tags: python, oop, scope

I have a class "Wrapper". Wrapper inherits from object, and it's primary responsibility is to hook method calls to selenium during a test. It's `__init__` method signature is

```
__init__(self, object_to_wrap, actions={}, **kwargs)
```

Part of it's functionality is to take a dictionary as an argument in the init method, and to expose the keys as attributes on the `object_to_wrap` object by defining the `__getattr__` magic method
(signature: `__getattr__(self, item):`) 
and checking `self.actions`'s keys for `item`. If it is found, the method is invoked.

In the test code, the initialization would look similar to:

```
def navigate(scoped_self, to=''):
    self.driver.switch_to_default_content()
    self.driver.switch_to.frame(to)
    scoped_self.navigations.append(to)
    # the navigate method is scoped in an
    # instance method of the test class, so it has access to self
```

So, my question is, how can I make the scope, or `self` in the above method, be the scope of my `Wrapper` class, and not the test class?

For clarity, if the solution I am looking for in this question was found, the navigate implementation would change to be:

```
def navigate(scoped_self, to=''):
    self.object_to_wrap.switch_to_default_content()
    self.object_to_wrap.switch_to.frame(to)
```

Also for clarity, I'm pretty sure what I'm looking for is exactly what Javascripts `Function.prototype.bind` accomplishes.

**UPDATE**: Defining the methods, such as navigate, inside the Wrapper class is not an option, as the Wrapper class **cannot** have test-specific logic. The test suite is done on n > 1 DOM, that are completely unrelated. For example, one of the tests requires the method "alert_handlers" (to overwrite the window.alert function and return the alerts presented as a string), another might require the navigate method, and a third might require both.

**UPDATE #2**: Thanks to the answer below from c17r, I realized that without the **getattribute** code included in my example, that it would appear as if I was asking for something we had already accomplished. What I am looking for is the ability, in the above navigate method, is for `scoped_self` to be the instance of Wrapper.

Furthermore, I am specifically looking for a way to "dynamically" pass scoped_self to the functions (the way that `Function.prototype.bind`"dynamically" sets `this` where `this` is myEventListener.bind(window); if you're unfamiliar with javascript, make an event listener on the body and console.log `this` **without** binding, and then with binding, to see the difference)

Furthermore, I figured it might help to give an example implementation **without the solution I am looking for**. This is currently working as expected:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped, actions={}):
        self.wrapped = wrapped
        self.actions = actions
        self.navigations = [] # EXAMPLE, SEE THE TEST CLASS CODE

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item in self.actions:
           return self.actions[item]
        # do other fancy stuff here
        # UPDATE #2: added for clarity. this is the current implementation
        orig_attr = self.wrapped.__getattribute__(item)
        if callable(orig_attr):
            def hooked(*args, **kwargs):
                self.pre(item, *args, **kwargs)
                self.err = False
                try:
                    result = orig_attr(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    #logs
                    self.post(*args, **kwargs)
                    raise
            if type(self.wrapped) == type(result):
                return self
            return result
        return hooked
    else:
        return orig_attr

class SomeTest():
    #blah blah init stuff, set self.driver = selenium.webdriver.Phantomjs
    def spawn_actions(self):
        def navigate(scoped_self, to=''):
            self.driver.switch_to_default_content()
            self.driver.switch_to.frame(to)
            scoped_self.navigations.append(to) # <--- appended to wrapper.navigations       
        return {'navigate': navigate}

    def run(self):
        driver = Wrapper(self.driver, self.spawn_actions())
        driver.get(url)
        driver.navigate('New Request')
        # fun tests!
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, 3 things:

1. `Wrapper` would need to pass any unknown functions down to the wrapped item, otherwise `driver.get()` won't work properly.
2. The `navigate` function needs `self` as the first parameter, like it would if it was actually defined on `Wrapper`
3. `Wrapper` needs to pass `self` into the dict-based function.  This is a little tricky since `__getattr__` doesn't actually call the function, so you need to return a function that calls the underlying function properly, similar to how decorators work.

Like this:

```
class Driver(object):
    def get(self, url):
        print('get')
        print(repr(self))
        print(repr(url))
        print('--')


class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped, actions={}):
        self.wrapped = wrapped
        self.actions = actions

    def __getattr__(self, item):            
        if item in self.actions:
            def unwrap(*args, **kwargs):
                return self.actions[item](self, *args, **kwargs)
            return unwrap
        else:
            return getattr(self.wrapped, item)


class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = Driver();

    def spawn_actions(self):
        def navigate(self, to=''):
            print('navigate')
            print(repr(self))
            print(repr(to))
            print(repr(self.wrapped))
            print('--')

        return {
            'navigate': navigate
        }

    def run(self):
        driver = Wrapper(self.driver, self.spawn_actions())
        driver.get('url')
        driver.navigate('thing')
```

Now calling:

```
t = Test()
t.run()
```

Outputs:

```
get
<__main__.Driver object at 0x104008630>
'url'
--
navigate
<__main__.Wrapper object at 0x104008ba8>
'thing'
<__main__.Driver object at 0x104008630>
--
```

**EDIT**

You can also dynamically bind the methods to the instance instead of `__getattr__` returning the `unwrap` function:

```
import types
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped, actions={}):
        self.wrapped = wrapped

        for name, func in actions.items():
            setattr(self, name, types.MethodType(func, self))

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.wrapped, item)
```

Comment: You did understand me correctly, and I apologize for leaving out all of __getattr__ (for brevity). see my update on what the actual implementation looks like. Note that there will be more than one instance method called that I will not be including in the code, again for brevity (and because it's too close to production code for our product)

Comment: However, after thoroughly rereading your code, I believe you've answered my question :) I'll test as soon as I get to the machine where I have the implementation.